# Using Atom and Github for Windows

Tags: github, text-editor

small question, I use atom text editor, today I installed Github for windows. Since all my commits messages triggered notepad.exe, I used the following line to change my global editor:

```
 git config --global core.editor atom
```

Now everytime I try to commit something, atom start and open the indicated file, but in my powershell windows, git says:

```
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```

There is any guide or config settings to make atom work with github for windows?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution suggested by a person in the atom discussion forum:

```
 git config --global core.editor 'atom --wait'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to use GitHub for Windows with Atom.  I was wondering if you could share how you set yourself up.  I have git-plus package installed in Atom, I have it pointed at my GitHub.exe for Windows executable.  When I try to do a Git Add All Commit and Push (Ctrl+Shift+A P) from within Atom, even if I've added a new folder/file, it opens up several copies of GitHub.exe but none of them actually 'Sync' with my GitHub account.  I have used the Windows-based Git Shell to do the following:

```
git config --global user.name "First Last"
git config --global user.email myemail@domain.com
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

Finally, I've noticed that completely outside of Atom, you must type something in the 'summary' field in GitHub for Windows in order for sync to actually push files to my GitHub account.  To me this is the same as CLI:  git commit -m 'summary'.  I don't know how Atom would push a summary into that field so I'm not sure Atom will ever properly work with GitHub for Windows.

Comment: can u suggest some alternate solution

Comment: I suppose you could purchase and use an IDE which supports Git natively.  Given that Atom is made by Git, it's a bit shocking to me that they don't support it natively.  Or maybe I'm not understanding something.